# Values updating on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hiii, I am having problem with a code.
here is my structure, I have **class structure** as follows :

```
.box-slide-query

---.new-query-blocks

---.query-blocks

---.query-blocks

---.query-blocks
```

I need on click of .new-query-blocks class, i should get the count of number of .query-blocks. I am able to get the value but it is working when i click 2 times(On second click it update the value in attr "answerCount").

here's my **code :**

```
$('html').on('click', '.new-query-blocks', function () {
    $('.query-result').each(function () {
        ($('.box-slide-query')).attr('answerCount', $('.new-question-row', $(this)).length);
    });
});
```

Comment: can you share the html

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle...?

Comment: what is `query-result`? and `new-question-row`

Comment: Try $(document) instead of $('html') and in selector parameter specify exact (like parent > child) selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('html').on('click', '.new-query-blocks', function () {
    $('html').find('.query-result').each(function () {
        ($('.box-slide-query')).attr('answerCount', $('.new-question-row', $(this)).length);
    });
});
```